# problems to update templade briefcase beeware

Tags: android, beeware

I am stucked with a problem, I am trying to execute,
"briefcase create android"

But I am not able to run it, i get the following error, does anyone know how to solve it.

[image]

I dont really know where to start, I am a newbie :)

Comment: The red message already contains a suggestion for what to do. If that doesn't work, please create an issue on the [Briefcase GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues), and attach a copy of the log file mentioned at the bottom of the error.